# How to fetch data from ajax data object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fetch date format in the form of json object from database. The code is like

```
                   $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?action=getDateFormat',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function(data){
                        if (data.length) 
                        {
                           var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
                           return jsonData["DateFormat"];
                        }
                      }
                });
```

Note that in console of browser, the data is "Object { dateFormat: "d-m-Y" }".

The above code is returning "undefined". Please help !!!

in php code

```
         $dateFormatArray = array("dateFormat" => $dateFormat);
         json_encode( $dateFormatArray);
```

In console of browser the result of data is

```
         Object { dateFormat: "d-m-Y" }
```

Full code

```
         function getDateFormat()
            {
                var dateFormat ="";
                 $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?action=getDateFormat',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        dateFormat = data.dateFormat;
                    }
                });

                return dateFormat; 
            }
```

Comment: key is case sensitive. `jsonData["dateFormat"];`

Comment: it still shows undefined

Comment: can you share the output for statement `console.log(jsonData["DateFormat"])` within that `if` condition.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: can you share the output of `console.log(data)` before `parse` statement?

Comment: Object { dateFormat: "d-m-Y" }

Comment: That parse statement wasn't required, just `data.dateFormat` would do. Also, you can't return from a async method

Comment: oh thanks... how will i return data.dateformat to another function

Comment: Check the answers provided in the original question.

Comment: I have updated my question with full code... it is returning null value to another function in which it is called

Comment: Did you read the answers in the Original question? You cannot return a value from a method which is getting that value from an asynchronous operation.

Comment: yes.... is there any ways to accomplish this